# setTimeout в цикле

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Как я понял, `setTimeout` запускает функции через нужное нам время.
Т.е. в цикле каждая итерация задерживается на наш timeout.

Исходя из этого моего знания вопрос:
Почему работает как задумано только первая итерация цикла и как исправить?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {console.log("sample");}, 4000);
};
```

Скорее всего я неверно понял как пользоваться `setTimeout`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код практически одновременно заказывает 10 таймаутов. В Вашем примере все они - через 4 секунды. Вот они все 10 и выполнятся практически одновременно. В моем они заказаны через одну, две, три и т.д. секунды.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log("sample"); }, 1000 * (i + 1));
}
```

Comment: Что, как?
Дайте хоть почитать где-то, я искал, честно.

Почему сообщение всегда выводится через 4с, почему не 8,12 и т.д.?

Comment: @tranntus нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код"

Comment: да я понял что работает, я не понял почему, там просто должно менятся значение миллисекунд обязательно?

Comment: @tranntus А теперь?

Comment: дай бог здоровья вам короче

Comment: @tranntus а вы еще в консоли переменную `i`, `console.log("sample",i);` напишите - еще больше удивитесь!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko , т.е. идет повторение всегда последней итерации цикла чтоли? i = 10 всегда.
Как это вообще работает

Comment: @tranntus Это вам надо про замыкания читать...

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko , а причем тут они? i объявлена в функции выше, в анонимке используется i сверху, страшно видеть совет про читайте замыкания, если ты прошел недавно на курсах это тему :)

Comment: @tranntus Ну как при чем.. При том самом! Поэтому и про замыкания надо читать)

Answer (score -1):

При вызове функция становится в очередь на выполнение. Запустилась и смотрит, когда ей пора выполняться: ага, через 1 сек... И так 10 функций. Когда приходит время выполняться, цикл уже прокрутился, i = 10. Получается у вас в очереди стоит 10 функций с одинаковой командой вывести в консоль i, которая на тот момент уже равна 10.