# Не работает setTimeout() в цикле

Tags: javascript, ajax

У меня есть функция с вот такой частью кода:

```
for(let i=0; i<=IDarray.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => $.ajax ({
        url: "parse.php",
         type: "POST",
          data: ({ id: IDarray[i] }),
          dataType: "text",
          success: funcSuccessID
    }), 2000);
}
```

IDarray здесь - это массив, содержащий ID пользователей, которые я пытаюсь обработать. Почему тут может не работать setTimeout()?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что setTimeout не работает?

Comment: `i<=IDarray.length` - должно быть `<`

Comment: Я думаю, что не работает, потому что при запуске программы я вижу, что он не работает. Слишком быстро выводятся значения, как для 2х секундной задержки. И да, меньше или равно на меньше исправил

Comment: Все работает, нужно [указать правильный интервал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/786317/186999)